# WIN-PROLOG - how to get random value?

Tags: random, prolog, win-prolog

I'm using LPA WIN-PROLOG and I want to get random values.
I looked for a random predicate and I don't find one that is already defined.
What I tried:

`X is random(10)`

`random(1,10,X)`

Can someone help me find the way to get a random value?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a commercial product without a public manual. Perhaps you could email them and get support that way? If I were guessing, I would try `X is random()` and hope to get back a float value between 0 and 1.

Comment: @DanielLyons , thanks but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LPA Win-Prolog provides a `rand/1` built-in function and a `seed/1` predicate to get/set the seed of the random number generator. The `rand/1` function returns a float between zero and its argument. For example:

```
?- seed(42), Random is rand(10).
```